# Cannot add files to a specific folder using file resumable module

Tags: files

I recently moved to a droplet at DigitalOcean. Because they have small hdd's I added 20GB extra space to my droplet.

Because my resources does not fit neither on extra space or on the server's hdd I split the

> sites/default/files

folder by creating 2 symlinks  for 2 folders that hold around 15GB pointing to the extra space.

Now if I try to create a node of the type that should put the files in the extra space I get this error:

```
The upload directory public://xxx for the file field field_fisiere_audio could not be created or is not accessible. A newly uploaded file could not be saved in this directory as a consequence, and the upload was canceled.
```

All the folders where I upload files have 700 rights. The owner and group is www-data.

Any idea why do I get this? Is this because of the symlinks? Is there any other way of splitting the files folder?

I also tried with 777 and is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Because I was pressed by time I made the following changes:

1 I moved the whole sites folder to the extra space (after I bought
   some more)

2  I created a symlink to sites

Everything seems to be working ok.

My idea is that inside files drupal can't handle symlinks.